# How to determine the maximum number of memory cells a computer can have

Tags: memory, hardware, memory-address

If a computer memory has addresses that are **n bits** long, what is the maximum number of memory cells that computer can have?

Can you even determine this based solely on the number of bits in the addresses?

I'm looking for what a formula would be to calculate the maximum number of memory cells based on the bit size of the memory cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of cells that can be accessed on a N bit computer is generally 2 to the Nth power.  That does not imply that it is all RAM memory.  Some of it may be consumed by the operating system.  The processor may use some of it for memory mapped IO.  Some of it may be reserved for future use.   I had a PC back in the 80s, that also had banked memory.  Basically your program could call an operating system function, and it swapped out one bank of memory for another.  This was the era of 16 bit processors.  64k addressable space was the maximum you could have.

Comment: Thank you! That is similar to what is in my book, but it wasn't worded as clearly. I appreciate the response, thanks again!